# How can I download a Sample from Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, sdk, sample

I want to download the FingerPaint sample, but I don't know how to.

I already looked at this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

But, there are no samples in my SDK Manager. What am I doing wrong?

Print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwvxl.png

How can I download the samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the sdk again, and some samples appeared.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom bar, where `Show` option is there, you have the `Installed` checkbox checked. Uncheck it. Then you will see the samples. Check the sample you want to download & click on install. As easy as that!

Comment: Still does not appear the samples.

Am I doing something wrong? http://i.imgur.com/rl8wS.png

Answer (score 0):

In your sdk file, open "SDK Manager" or (Android studio -> Settings ->Android SDK, click "Launch Standalone SDK Manager"), then select Samples for SDK to download.